# Does ReSharper have the inverse of "move initializer to constructor?"

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper will offer to move a field initializer to the constructor:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to reverse the process - to move initialization from a constructor to a field initializer.

That is, starting with:

```
class C
{
    readonly int i;

    public C()
    {
        i = 42;
    }
}
```

end with:

```
class C
{
    readonly int i = 42;

    public C() { }
}
```

Does ReSharper support that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this.

In order to do so from this starting position:

```
class Program
{
        public Program()
        {
           int i = 42;
        }
}
```

Put your cursor on the line of `int i = 42;` (you might have to toy around a little, I believe it only worked when I put my cursor in front of the `i` when I tried it), go to  <kbd>Resharper</kbd>  ->  <kbd>Refactor</kbd>  ->  <kbd>Introduce Field</kbd> .

Select  <kbd>Field initializer</kbd>  and  <kbd>Make field readonly</kbd> .

Result:

```
class Program
{
        private readonly int _i = 42;

        public Program()
        {
        }
}
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Introduce_Field.html).

Comment: I don't want to move a local to a field - I want to move the *initializer* of the field. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @Jay the trick is to remove the field. Resharer will then suggest to introduce the field for the assignment. Alt+Enter for the quick-fix, and set to initialize in declaration. This would be my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Structural Search and Replace.

Here's a [SSR pattern for you](https://gist.github.com/gorohoroh/8337921/raw/942c84671dbccbabe8c64f84301228ecadd079e9/move_initialization_from_constructor_to_field.DotSettings)

It works with your simple example but may need to be modified to match more sophisticated cases, or even turn out to not support them. Anyway play with it.

To import the template, go to **ReSharper > Manage Options**, right-click an existing layer (if required, create a new layer beforehand), select **Import from > Import from URL** and specify the raw gist URL above.

As soon as you're done, a new code inspection should appear, with a quick-fix to move initialization to the field.

If necessary, go to **ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Custom Patterns** to edit the pattern or configure inspection severity.